# The value of my integers is not showing in my black jack program c#

Tags: c#, integer, blackjack

I am trying to complete a very simple black jack program.  What I seem to having trouble with is the fact that there are no numbers being generated for card one and two.  This is my code so far:

```
namespace Black_Jack
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int card1, card2;
        float total;          

            Console.WriteLine("Value of card one:");
            Random card = new Random();
            card1 = card.Next(1, 12);
            Console.WriteLine("Value of card two:");
            card2 = card.Next(1, 12);
            total = card1 + card2;            

            {
                if (total >= 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Busted!");
                }
                else if (total == 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Black Jack! You Win Mr. Vegas!");
                }
                else if (total < 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I'll stand. Show me your cards dealer!");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

I am not quite sure where my problem is, so an explanation of what I am doing incorrectly would be very helpful.  Also, if there is anything else that should be cleaned up please let me know.

Comment: If linked duplicate is not enough please read documentation on `Console.WriteLine` and [edit] question explaining what you've tried and how it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by declaring **total** as **int**

```
Int total;
total = card1 + card2; // assign integers sum to integer variable
```

Or you can use **casting**

```
Total = (float)(card1 + card2); // converts integers sum to float
```

And,

```
card1 = card.Next(1, 12);
```

After this line line print your **random** number

```
Console.WriteLine(card1); // similar for both card
```

Comment: I was able to declare total as int, but my program is still not displaying any numbers after the "Value of card one" and "value of card two".  Does that mean there is a problem in my output?

Comment: Because you are not printing the numbers.
Wait ill edit my answer

Comment: Print both random number after generating them

Comment: So that was all it took.  Thank you for your help, I always seem to forget something as simple as that.  Now it generates the numbers randomly and I was able to write another line that displays the total.  I can't believe I forgot something as simple as that.

Comment: Plz upvote and mark as answered if it help.thnx